# Showing that any two elements in two normal subgroups commute

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group and $N$ and $M$ normal subgroups of $G$ such that $M\cap N = \{1_G\}$. Show that $\forall m\in M, n\in N$ we have $mn=nm$

My attempt: In the given conditions we have $mn\in mN = Nm$, the last equality because $N$ is normal. Then $nm = am$ for some $a\in N$. But then by the cancellation law we have $a=n$ and then $nm=mn$.

But this seems strange to me because I have not used the condition that $M$ is normal and that $M, N$ have only the identity element in common. Or did I and I don't see where? Can someone help me clarify this question?

(Note that this is not the same question as, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098301/using-the-properites-of-normal-subgroups-to-show-that-two-elements-commute), because I'm asking for verification on my attempt).

Comment: I can't follow your argument.  You (correctly) argue that $mn\in Nm$ which would tell us that $mn=am$ for some $a\in N$, but I don't see how you deduce that $nm$ can be written as $am$.

Comment: You seem to have erred in switching from the product $mn$ to $nm$, though perhaps you just didn't fully articulate the point you have in mind.  Yes, $mn= am$ for some $a\in N$ by normality, but you did not say why that $a$ must be $n$.  I suspect this is whether the other facts  (normality of $M$ and trivial intersection) come into the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m \in M$ and $n \in N$. Then $mnm^{-1} \in N$ and $n^{-1} \in N$ so that $mnm^{-1}n^{-1} \in N$.

Also, $nm^{-1}n^{-1} \in M$ so that $m(nm^{-1}n^{-1}) \in M$.

Hence, $mnm^{-1}n^{-1} \in M\cap N = \{1_{G}\} \implies mnm^{-1}n^{-1} = 1_{G}$ and the result follows.